# Django HTML E-mail template can't load imported css?

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates, django-email

Now I'm creating an email template using CSS defined in other files, which I imported into the template. I formatted the template using render_to_string("my_email.html") before sending it via email. The email was sent, however the template email could not load my imported CSS.

I have tried but it didn't load imported css. Then my email content didn't have css.

Comment: for email templates the common practice is to have the css in the html file inside the `<style></style>` tag

Comment: It's better to use inline CSS for email templates. Idk why? but it's very weird that email template not recognize the CSS in `style` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Email template load only **`inline css`** or **`<style></style>`** which you are wrote in template it's not load **`cdn`** or **`external css`** from file

Here I put one sample template try to send in email it's working fine template name is **`index.html`**

#### Django E-Mail Sending Code

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils.html import strip_tags

def HomeView(request):
    dynamic_data = {
        'variable_name': 'Dynamic Content',
        # Add more variables as needed
    }
    html_message = render_to_string("test.html",dynamic_data)
    plain_message = strip_tags(html_message)

    message = EmailMultiAlternatives(
        subject = "Test E-Mail", 
        body = plain_message,
        from_email = "sender@email.com",
        to= ["receiver@email.com"])

    message.attach_alternative(html_message, "text/html")
    message.send()

    context = {
      'name':'Rahul'
    }
    return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

#### Html Template

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<style type="text/css">

body, table, td, a { -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
table, td { mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; }
img { -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }

img { border: 0; height: auto; line-height: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; }
table { border-collapse: collapse !important; }
body { height: 100% !important; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; width: 100% !important; }


a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
    color: inherit !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font-size: inherit !important;
    font-family: inherit !important;
    font-weight: inherit !important;
    line-height: inherit !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .mobile-hide {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .mobile-center {
        text-align: center !important;
    }
}
div[style*="margin: 16px 0;"] { margin: 0 !important; }
</style>
<body style="margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; background-color: #eeeeee;" bgcolor="#eeeeee">


<div style="display: none; font-size: 1px; color: #fefefe; line-height: 1px; font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; max-height: 0px; max-width: 0px; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden;">
For what reason would it be advisable for me to think about business content? That might be little bit risky to have crew member like them. 
</div>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" style="background-color: #eeeeee;" bgcolor="#eeeeee">
        
        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:600px;">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:0; padding: 35px;" bgcolor="#F44336">
               
                <div style="display:inline-block; max-width:50%; min-width:100px; vertical-align:top; width:100%;">
                    <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:300px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 36px; font-weight: 800; line-height: 48px;" class="mobile-center">
                                <h1 style="font-size: 36px; font-weight: 800; margin: 0; color: #ffffff;">BBBootstrap</h1>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                
                <div style="display:inline-block; max-width:50%; min-width:100px; vertical-align:top; width:100%;" class="mobile-hide">
                    <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:300px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" valign="top" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 48px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 48px;">
                                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="right">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 400;">
                                            <p style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: 400; margin: 0; color: #ffffff;"><a href="#" target="_blank" style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;">Shop &nbsp;</a></p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px;">
                                            <a href="#" target="_blank" style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/small-business.png" width="27" height="23" style="display: block; border: 0px;"/></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
              
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="padding: 35px 35px 20px 35px; background-color: #ffffff;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:600px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding-top: 25px;">
                            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/carbon-copy/100/000000/checked-checkbox.png" width="125" height="120" style="display: block; border: 0px;" /><br>
                            <h2 style="font-size: 30px; font-weight: 800; line-height: 36px; color: #333333; margin: 0;">
                                Thank You For Your Order!
                            </h2>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding-top: 10px;">
                            <p style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; color: #777777;">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium iste ipsa numquam odio dolores, nam.
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" style="padding-top: 20px;">
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="75%" align="left" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 800; line-height: 24px; padding: 10px;">
                                        Order Confirmation #
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="25%" align="left" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 800; line-height: 24px; padding: 10px;">
                                        2345678
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="75%" align="left" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 15px 10px 5px 10px;">
                                        Purchased Item (1)
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="25%" align="left" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 15px 10px 5px 10px;">
                                        $100.00
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="75%" align="left" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 5px 10px;">
                                        Shipping + Handling
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="25%" align="left" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 5px 10px;">
                                        $10.00
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="75%" align="left" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 5px 10px;">
                                        Sales Tax
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="25%" align="left" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 5px 10px;">
                                        $5.00
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" style="padding-top: 20px;">
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="75%" align="left" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 800; line-height: 24px; padding: 10px; border-top: 3px solid #eeeeee; border-bottom: 3px solid #eeeeee;">
                                        TOTAL
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="25%" align="left" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 800; line-height: 24px; padding: 10px; border-top: 3px solid #eeeeee; border-bottom: 3px solid #eeeeee;">
                                        $115.00
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                
                </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td align="center" height="100%" valign="top" width="100%" style="padding: 0 35px 35px 35px; background-color: #ffffff;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:660px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:0;">
                            <div style="display:inline-block; max-width:50%; min-width:240px; vertical-align:top; width:100%;">

                                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:300px;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px;">
                                            <p style="font-weight: 800;">Delivery Address</p>
                                            <p>675 Massachusetts Avenue<br>11th Floor<br>Cambridge, MA 02139</p>

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <div style="display:inline-block; max-width:50%; min-width:240px; vertical-align:top; width:100%;">
                                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:300px;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px;">
                                            <p style="font-weight: 800;">Estimated Delivery Date</p>
                                            <p>January 1st, 2016</p>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style=" padding: 35px; background-color: #ff7361;" bgcolor="#1b9ba3">
                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:600px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding-top: 25px;">
                            <h2 style="font-size: 24px; font-weight: 800; line-height: 30px; color: #ffffff; margin: 0;">
                                Get 30% off your next order.
                            </h2>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="padding: 25px 0 15px 0;">
                            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" style="border-radius: 5px;" bgcolor="#66b3b7">
                                      <a href="#" target="_blank" style="font-size: 18px; font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 5px; background-color: #F44336; padding: 15px 30px; border: 1px solid #F44336; display: block;">Shop Again</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="padding: 35px; background-color: #ffffff;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:600px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <img src="logo-footer.png" width="37" height="37" style="display: block; border: 0px;"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 5px 0 10px 0;">
                            <p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 800; line-height: 18px; color: #333333;">
                                675 Parko Avenue<br>
                                LA, CA 02232
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px;">
                            <p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 20px; color: #777777;">
                                If you didn't create an account using this email address, please ignore this email or <a href="#" target="_blank" style="color: #777777;">unsusbscribe</a>.
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
    
</body>
</html>
```

##### NOTE - all css wrote in **`<style></style>`** tag template